Inverse problem in 2D electrostatics
Imagine you're trying to figure out the shape $S$ of a charge distribution $\rho(x,y)$ in a embedded in a region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, but you only have information about the electric field $E(x,y)$ outside of $\Omega$.
In general it is not possible to evaluate $\rho$ or $E$ by analytic continuation from outside the region, because the charge distribution is not completely determined by the value of the electric field outside the charged region.
Fortunately, while it is not possible to get an expression for $\rho(x,y)$, it is at least possible to infer the shape, i.e. the region where $\rho(x,y)\neq 0$. This is called an inverse problem in Potential theory. However, in practice I am not sure how to proceed. What would be the equations one is looking to solve?

No, it is not possible in general. You cannot infer anything on the support of $\rho$ just by knowing the field outside a domain containing it.
In fact, it is rather the opposite, you need some assumptions on the distribution of charge to infer anything inside $\Omega$. You can build intuition in 2D, using complex analysis. Considering $E(z) = E_x-iE_y$, with $z=x+iy$. The line integral is:
$$
\oint Edz = C+i\Phi
$$
with $C$ the circulation of $\vec E$ along the loop, and $\Phi$ the flux across the loop:
$$
C = \int\vec E\cdot d\vec x \quad \Phi = \int\vec E\cdot d\vec x_\perp
$$
Point charges correspond to simple poles with real residues. Thus, if $E$ admits a meromorphic continuation in $\Omega$ (which is unique) and you assume that the charge distribution consists of isolated point charges, then yes, you can fully determine $\rho$ in $\Omega$.
This generalises even when the charges coalesce to a curve. They form a branch cut of $E$. If you know the branch cut, then you can meromorphically continue the function and uniquely determine the charge distribution, again assuming it is punctual or along curves. Take for example $E = \frac1{2\pi\sqrt{z^2-1}}$. By choosing the branch cut $[-1,1]$ you can uniquely continue $E$, but by choosing a different branch cut, you will get a different charge distribution.
